# Setting up cocoa pods with a react native project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I've set up a fresh react native project, and instantiated a cocoa pod .xcworkspace doing:

```
cd ios
pod init 
pod install
```

I've then added a pod that I want to use (in this case being Buddybuild, although it doesn't really matter which pod i add, as the behavior is similar)

After I run `pod install` and include the header `#import <BuddyBuildSDK/BuddyBuildSDK.h>` in my `AppDelegate.m` , it is always returning me a `/Users/nik/dev/myproject/ios/myproject/AppDelegate.m:14:9: 'BuddyBuildSDK/BuddyBuildSDK.h' file not found`

I've battled with this all day and I have no idea why. The headers are all there in the `Pods/headers/Public` folder. They're being included in the header search paths in build settings as well as you can see here:

[image]

I'd highly appreciate help on this as I'm very stuck.

*EDIT* Also here's my `Podfile`:

[image]

Comment: are you sure pods are installed correctly?

Comment: i'm relatively positive. i ran all the appropriate commands. i mean, how can i check?

Comment: try to import any framework what it says.?

Comment: any framework results in a `SomeFramework/SomeFramework.h' file not found`

Comment: your pods are not installed properly.

Comment: uncomment use_framework in your pod file and do pod install again.

Comment: i actually finally solved it! Will post answer in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was an xcode thing. After much Googling the issue that solved it was making sure that my projects configurations were properly set. So going to `Project` -> `Info` -> `Configurations` And choosing the right `Pods-projectName.debug` and `Pods-projectName.release` configurations.

Comment: Are you using custom build configurations by any chance? I'm trying to get pods to work but it's not building them because the custom build configurations are using Release

Comment: @SimonTheEngineer I wasn't using any custom configurations. I wish I could help but this was long ago and I've long stopped working on that project :( Sorry

Answer (score 0):

For **RN 0.58.6** I noticed you don't need any react or react-native pods.

If you create a brand new project using react-native init (for 0.58.6) you will notice there is no need for a pod file.

My `pod` file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
project 'MyRNProject.xcodeproj'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'MyRNProject' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Add pods that you need here

  target 'MyRNProject' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

In Project target `Linked framework or libraries` I have:

- *framework deps* `(CoreFoundation.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework Pods_MyRNProject.framework etc)`
- `RCT` and `RN` deps
- other libs that I use

[image]

[image]